# Using Mencoder to Convert Sequence of Images Sorted Numerically to Video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, file-conversion, mencoder

I want to use `mencoder` to convert a sequence of PNG files to video. The PNG files are named like {`file1.png, file2.png, ... file1000.png`}. However, if I run this:

```
mencoder mf://*.png -mf fps=25 -ovc copy -oac copy output.avi
```

The resulting video will not stitch together the frames in the correct order (correct: 1,2,3,.... incorrect: 1, 10, 100, ...). Answers to a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656371/mencoder-and-sequence-of-pictures) suggest that I can manually input the range of frames to have mencoder use the correct numerical order:

```
mencoder mf://file{1..1000}.png -mf fps=25 -ovc copy -oac copy output.avi
```

or to manually sort the files with something like `ls -v` and then save the results to a list (say, `list.txt`), and then pass that into `mencoder`:

```
mencoder mf://@list.txt -mf fps=25 -ovc copy -oac copy output.avi
```

However, my question is: **Is there a way to do this in a single command without specifying the last frame?**

Ideally, I would want an equivalent to `mf://file*.png` that uses a numerical sorting as opposed to the default sorting. For example, `ffmpeg` has the option to specify input files like `file%d.png`, which would order the files numerically.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use ffmpeg for this?

Comment: ffmpeg would probably work as well, but the codebase I'm working with uses mencoder elsewhere.

Comment: Ok - workaround if you don't find a direct soln is to read sequence using ffmpeg and pipe it using image2pipe to mencoder.

Comment: @txizzle Did you get this sorted? I'm looking for a robust commandline that takes an arbitrary series of sequence-images (named either eg. *0001 or *1, *2 .. etc). Did they improve this in MEncoder (too lazy to investigate)?